# Why i am getting this error 'FORMAT FARE BASIS NOT AVAILABLE'?

Tags: sabre

My Request and Response xml StructureFareRulesRQ for one way trip.This works fine for single OriginDestinationOption. But with two and more stops it return error. But with two and more stops it return error. But with two and more stops it return error. But with two and more stops it return error.

```
<StructureFareRulesRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" Version="1.0.4" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <PriceRequestInformation BuyingDate="2019-05-17T04:41:34" CurrencyCode="NPR">
        <PassengerTypes>
          <PassengerType Code="ADT" Count="1"/>
        </PassengerTypes>
        <ReturnAllData Value="1"/>
        <FreeBaggageSubscriber Ind="true"/>
      </PriceRequestInformation>

      <AirItinerary>
        <OriginDestinationOptions>

          <OriginDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDate="2019-06-19T15:50:00" ArrivalDate="2019-06-19T18:25:00" BookingDate="2019-05-17T04:41:34" FlightNumber="249" RealReservationStatus="SS" ResBookDesigCode="K" SegmentNumber="1" SegmentType="A">
              <DepartureAirport LocationCode="KTM"/>
              <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BOM"/>
              <MarketingAirline Code="9W"/>
              <OperatingAirline Code="9W"/>
            </FlightSegment>
            <SegmentInformation SegmentNumber="1"/>
            <PaxTypeInformation PassengerType="ADT" FareComponentNumber="1" FareBasisCode="K2OWNP"/>
          </OriginDestinationOption>

          <OriginDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDate="2019-06-19T22:35:00" ArrivalDate="2019-06-20T00:55:00" BookingDate="2019-05-17T04:41:34" FlightNumber="310" RealReservationStatus="SS" ResBookDesigCode="K" SegmentNumber="2" SegmentType="A">
              <DepartureAirport LocationCode="BOM"/>
              <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="DEL"/>
              <MarketingAirline Code="9W"/>
              <OperatingAirline Code="9W"/>
            </FlightSegment>
            <SegmentInformation SegmentNumber="2"/>
            <PaxTypeInformation PassengerType="ADT" FareComponentNumber="2" FareBasisCode="K2OWNP"/>
          </OriginDestinationOption>

        </OriginDestinationOptions>
      </AirItinerary>
    </StructureFareRulesRQ>


<StructureFareRulesRS Version="1.0.4" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Errors>
                <Error ErrorCode="005106" ErrorMessage="FORMAT FARE BASIS NOT AVAILABLE"/>
            </Errors>
        </StructureFareRulesRS>
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the FaireBasisCode is the same which is returned from BFM result. Usually the error means the code is invalid or no data available for the specified code

Comment: Also can you try keeping the FareComponentNumber="1" for both the segments.